# Installing CA Cert fails with no error

Tags: command-line, ssl

I have created a self-signed CA certificate and to install it I issue the following:

```
$ sudo cp ~/myCA.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

The output however is:

> Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
>   0 added, 0 removed; done.
>   Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
>   done.

Why `0 added`? What am I doing wrong?

Some context:

- This is on 16.04
- I have verified the file does get copied to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/`
- Setting file permissions on `/usr/share/ca-certificates/myCA.crt` to 644 makes no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html):

> It reads the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf. **Each line gives a pathname
>          of a CA certificate under  /usr/share/ca-certificates  that  should  be
>          trusted**.

My guess is that you did not make any changes to this file and thus did not specify that your new certificate should be considered trusted.

Comment: Indeed! Once I added the path (actually it looked like it should be a sub-path from /usr/share/ca-certificates/), and issued the command it worked ... sort of. This time it spew: "WARNING: myCA.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping", which is another story.

Comment: with `update-ca-certificates` that's not necessary